# how to register kryo serializer instances in storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm, avro, kryo

I'm desparately trying to configure serializer instances to use in my storm topology.

The storm documentation states, there are 2 ways to register serializers :

> ```
> 1. The name of a class to register. In this case, Storm will use Kryo’s FieldsSerializer to serialize the class. This may or may not be optimal for the class – see the Kryo docs for more details.
> 2. A map from the name of a class to register to an implementation of com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer.
> ```

I want to use 2. ->

> ```
> Map<String, Object> serializerConfig = new HashMap<String, Object>();
> serializerConfig.put(Record.class.getName(), new AvroSerializer(params));
> conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_KRYO_REGISTER, serializerConfig);
> ```

Unfortunately, this results in

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storm conf is not valid. Must be json-serializable
> ```

on topology submission.

Does anyone know how to do this (register serializer instances) ?

Thank you very much

Comment: How you are submitting your topology? code I mean.

Comment: StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, conf, topology);

Comment: by the way, AvroSerializer is my own implementation (KryoSerializer)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [method in the backtype.storm.Config class](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/Config.html#registerSerialization(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) to register your own class derived from Serializer.

For your example, put this in the main method that creates and submits the topology:

```
// Read in Storm Configuration
Config conf = new Config();
conf.registerSerialization(Record.class, AvroSerializer.class);
```

Comment: my question should be : "How to register an INSTANCE of a kryo serializer". How do you actually pass in parameters to your serializers ?

Comment: @Patrick Not knowing details of your particular case, is it possible for you to put the params themselves in the storm config and have the serializer code fetch them?

Answer (score 1):

As Steven Magana-Zook said above, you want to register the class in the config as he's done. This apparently doesn't let you pass in parameters, but if you look in [SerializationFactory.java](https://github.com/metamx/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/serialization/SerializationFactory.java#L169) in storm's source, you can see that it resolves various possible constructors of your serializer class, including several that contain the storm Config. You can stash your parameters in there.

So not what you were hoping for exactly but you should be able to reach the same end.