# how to pass configuration parameters to kryo serializers in storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm, kryo

The storm Config offers some convenience methods for registering serializers. (I'm talking about storm 0.9.2-incubating..)

```
registerSerialization(Class)
registerSerialization(Class, Class<? extends Serializer>)
registerSerialization(Map, Class, Class<? extends Serializer>)
```

If I understand correctly, the 3rd signature is for the case when you want to add a new serializer to a given config.

But how to configure serializer instances ? There are decorators, but you only can provide decorator classes, no instances.

What I'm looking for is a way to pass in configuration parameters to the serializers itself in my java code.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to register kryo serializer instances in storm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470639/how-to-register-kryo-serializer-instances-in-storm)